# Unable to trigger JsonRequest action in LUIS (Microsoft)

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-functions, azure-language-understanding

Trying to implement a simple NLP application which involves training the LUIS model to understand when it is asked for an individual's phone number. The model has been successfully trained and the utterances' entities have been correctly labeled with the appropriate intent being recognized:

[image: Here is the image.]

However, when a JsonRequest action has been specified, the action fails to trigger.
Even if the body to be sent is incorrect, I should get a bad input response at the very least. However, nothing seems to take place. The target URL responds to POST requests that carry a JSON string in its body.

[image: Here is an image of the action settings]
[image: Here is an image of the action settings]

Comment: to rule out it being an Azure Functions/auth issue. Could you have it point to an HTTP triggered Function (no webhook) with Auth set to anonymous? If you still don't see a message, it's very likely an issue on the sender's side.

Comment: First thing I did actually. Azure Functions is working smoothly. I am also slightly concerned with the alert that pops up alongside the action link in LUIS indicating that the feature will soon be deprecated. Was hoping someone knew any details regarding that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the rule is not triggered because employeeName (of type phonenumber?) is required but has a value of null.  Until all required entities are found, the action will not be triggered.  You don't show it, but further down in your json you should see the prompt for the employeename.  This is part of the dialog feature in LUIS where if you prompt for that and send back the answer the action binding would be triggered once the required values are found.

We would love feedback on the utility of action binding and dialogs in LUIS.  We are deprecating them because we believe there is relatively little value in having LUIS in the middle.  You have code which is calling the LUIS endpoint and gets back the entity bindings.  It is easy for you to ask for missing values and massage them into whatever form is needed for your action URL.  Your code can identify missing values in complex ways, synthesize prompts that incorporate values, etc.  This gives you much more power and lets us focus on doing other things in LUIS to make natural language understanding better.  We also have the Microsoft Bot Builder SDK which provides code building blocks for intelligent dialogs.

Comment: I see. Seems my initial 'action' configuration was at fault. Is there an exact data and time when this feature will be deprecated? Also, regarding the feedback on the utility of action bindings and dialogs in LUIS, Stackoverflow's guidelines discourages such interactions. Would love to post feedback regarding the service in the appropriate place though.